# nodejs reading data from foreach loop

Tags: javascript, node.js

i've got some txt files that have json data in them i'm reading them, then trying to get data

```
  async function asda() {
  var files = await fs.readdirSync(__dirname);
  files = files.filter((file) => file.endsWith(".txt"));
  var data = {};
  files.forEach(async (file) => {
    filedata = await fs.readFileSync(__dirname + `/${file}`);
    viewers = await JSON.parse(filedata).chatters;
    data[file] = viewers;
  });
  console.log(data);
}
asda();
```

`file` is a string `data` is an object but it logs an empty object at the end. What causes this?

Comment: Another one you should read https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-to-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call

Comment: Remove all `async`/`await` from your code and it will work. You use sync versions of `fs` functions